# What is the best way to fetch and delete SMS messages from Twilio?

Tags: .net, sms, twilio

I am using twilio.sugar to download my SMS messages. I have a dotnet service downloading them on a timer, processing the messages, and sending back responses. Something like this:

```
Twilio.sugar.Model.PhoneAutomation(Account).SMSMessageList.sms_messages()
```

This works, but I think I'm just getting the 50 most recent messages. What I want are the messages that are new since the last time I checked. My preference would be to delete them as/after I download them like POP3. If that's not possible, how are Twilio users supposed to prevent reprocessing the same messages? I get the impression that other's would like to do it this way but are similarly not finding a way to delete messages. My current solution is asinine. I'm saving a list of every sid that I process and just skipping those every time I download the list. If that lists goes bad, my program will reprocess a bunch of commands. So far from optimal that it hurts. I'm guessing that I'm missing something obvious or I'm not using this as intended.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about twilio.sugar but the SMS/Messages REST API is deprecated.

There's a new Messages API that also supports the HTTP DELETE.

Check if there's something like this in twilio.sugar:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message

Comment: Eternal sunshine of the spotless SMS queue! Thank you for your help :)